# 3dsMax reinstall ; I fear to lost 3d models ; where to look to save?

Tags: save, backup, 3dsmax, 3d-model

I'm a trainee working in a company using 3dsMax Design 2015. Because of bugs (software cannot be opened anymore) the admin will try to reinstall it. I have to save datas (I think of 3d models) but 3ds is so huge I fear I will forgot something.

(A lot of things are saved on a server, but we want to be sure we don't lost work by mistake)

I already ;

- did a zipped copy of 3dsmax folder (just in case)
- look in %appData% and found nothing but error reports

Can you help me and tell me where to look at, please?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default save folder for 3dsmax is located under:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\3dsMax\*
```

Make sure to check there.
Other then that folder - we cannot know where you saved things.
So make sure to check that folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had not checked there earlier. Now I think it safe to reinstall 3ds. For the other saves, they are parts of other projects (Unity, etc.) or already saved on the server, i believe nothing harmful will happen to them if we reinstall 3dsmax.